# Error msg: using version 1.0.0-alpha2 of the constraint library which is obsolete

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` in my layout file and I get the following error message. I am not able to find what is the right compile line to use in gradle.

My gradle file has this:

> compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'

[image]

Comment: Try using `alpha7`.

Comment: How/where to check in the future what is the latest version? I tried deleting the line from gradle file and then clicking on `ConstraintLayout` in the XML UI builder and it added `alpha5` to the gradle file by itself.

Comment: `alpha7` worked - thanks. I can mark  that as answer but would be good to know how to check the latest version in the future, especially when it's released and not in alpha anymore.

Comment: "How/where to check in the future what is the latest version?" -- beats me. `ConstraintLayout` itself is largely undocumented, and its distribution mechanism is especially undocumented. Once Android Studio 2.2 and `ConstraintLayout` each ship in final form, the suggestions that you get from Android Studio should at least be reasonable.

Comment: Got it, thanks. You can add your comment as answer because `alpha7` at least did get rid of my issue. I will try to stick to LinearLayout and RelativeLayout for my shipping apps for now.

Comment: You can also look which versions are available in the SDK Manager in Studio -- open the SDK tools tab, and check the "Show Package Details" at the bottom. If you look in the "Support Repository" section, you will see ConstraintLayout and whatever versions are available Also, option-return (on mac) when hovering above that line in the xml editor would have offered you to do the upgrade automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tactically, `alpha7` works.

In the future, I would imagine that Android Studio will provide better indicators of what the latest version is, just as it does for the classic Android Support libraries. However, Android Studio 2.2 and `ConstraintLayout` are each in pre-release form at the moment, so we're subject to their limitations.

Answer (score 5):

I tried many version, but i couldn't solve the issue!
Finally i let Android Studio to solve this issue.

In the XML file, Beside error message you can see this option! Click on that to import reccomonded version

[image]

or you can press alt+enter placing your cursor on error line

I got constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8, when i pressed alt+enter

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
```

Comment: I include the 1.0.0-alpha8 in build.gradle, I see the same warning, and 'Upgrade to recommended version' changes it to 1.0.0-alpha1. Reverse action...

Comment: Did u check if its alpha1 or beta1? I upgrated to beta2 now

Comment: @NareshR i got Beta3,  LOL .!! I guess, They haven't  released stable version.